# Which SVG features are supported by Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

Illustrator is able to open SVGs and save files as SVGs, but I've noticed that certain SVG features that are included in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/) -- especially styles like `@font-face` w/ base-64 content and `path` `fill` -- do not seem to work when opening an SVG created elsewhere (or hand-coded).

**Is there any documentation -- official or unofficial -- that explains which SVG features are supported by Adobe Illustrator?** (both for exporting and importing)

In particular I'm working with SVG 1.1 and Illustrator CS5, but I'd be happy to see some info on any version. I've checked the Adobe site and left [a message on the forum](https://forums.adobe.com/message/7096831) - with no luck thus far.